# Bash Script Can't Connect to Azure Postgres using ENV Vars - "The Username should be in <username@hostname> format"

Tags: postgresql, authentication, environment-variables, bash

I have a bash script that [exports ENV vars](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-envars.html) to use in connecting to an Azure Postgres DB (`mydb.postgres.database.azure.com`). For the user portion of that specifically it looks like this:

```
export PGUSER="postgres@mydb"
```

This works fine to connect to my local DB where the `@mydb` part isn't required, but it fails when connecting to Azure (where it is required) with:

> psql: FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in username@hostname format.

I've found lots of solutions/answers to this like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49770598/177920) and [this one](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6371#issuecomment-376997025) however those aren't viable solutions when using ENV vars to set connection details (and while I didn't expect it to work I nonetheless tried changing my script to `export PGUSER="postgres%40mydb"` and indeed it did yield the same error).

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: PGUSER might be superseded. Please show the psql options on the command line and any other detail that might be relevant.

Comment: @DanielVérité Thanks, I linked to current docs in first sentence of my question. It's still supported, and as mentioned it works fine if there's no `@` required in the username.  There are no `psql` options on the command line, that's the point of exporting the env vars.

Comment: OK. PostgreSQL as released publicly does not have an error that says _The Username should be in username@hostname format_, this is an Azure-specific change. You should file a support ticket to Azure for this one.

Comment: In addition to the mystery of why it does not work on Azure, I guess there is also the mystery of why it does work locally.  It certainly doesn't for me I get `FATAL:  role "postgres@mydb" does not exist`.  Have you inspected the env to make sure it is actually set the way you think it is?

Comment: @jjanes I assume the `@mydb` part of that user identifier is not req'd in your environment, it also is not in mine.  It is however required with Azure.

Comment: It isn't that is "not required" in my system.  It is required to not be there.  Unless you have done something out of the ordinary to your local system to make it allowed, I would say the most likely explanation is that your attempt to set the ENV is failing to do what you think it does.

Comment: @jjanes communication breakdown. When I say _"This works fine to connect to my local DB where the @mydb part isn't required"_ I mean that using env var to set the user ID to *only* `postgres` w/o the `@mydb` part works.  I'm not using `@mydb` locally in any way.